# How Americans pronounce the T in party?

Tags: pronunciation

I have a simple question. I'm just asking about the direction of motion of the tongue (or the tip of the tongue).

I know that the tongue moves from the R (initial position). Then, it quickly hits the alveolar tap or edge. Then, it rests for the E sound (final position).

I'd like to know if the tongue moves from inside of the mouth or an inner position to an outer position or from out to in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some speakers the articulation there can sound closer to [d] than to [t].

> Pardy on, dude. Pardy on.

It depends where on the roof of the mouth the tongue makes contact. The farther back, the more the sounds shades towards [d].

The vowel in the first syllable, colored by [r], can be rather farther back in the throat than the counterpart in BrE, which is a more open vowel; that [r] can result in the cheeks tensing and the chin being pulled back as well, so that for some speakers of AmE there's quite a distance for the tongue to travel, indeed for the entire lower jaw to travel, to produce [t] and less distance for it to travel to produce [d].

An AmE speaker who retracts the lower jaw to produce [par] is almost guaranteed to articulate the consonant as [d].

But the direction of movement of the tongue to make the  d/t is never front-to-back.

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, I would really like to know what is amiss with my description. There is no single way that Americans say "party" and the sounds can be a [d] or a [t]. Anonymous downvotes without explanations are really tiresome.

Comment: Upvote from me, because I absolutely agree. I've heard native U.S. guys pronouncing "party", and it was far from [t]. Sometimes I even hardly heard a [d], so the sound seemed to get lost somewhere between r and y. But I would like to add that pronunciation generally depends on the native region of the speaker - in any country.

Comment: It was most likely downvoted because most of the answer is wrong.  "The farther back, the more the sounds shades towards [d]." is nonsense. You've put symbols in square brackets, indicating a close phonetic transcription, but all of your phonetic symbols indicate the wrong sounds – I doubt you really trill your r's!  Yes, the /t/ is normally voiced, but it's neither [t] nor [d]. It's the voiced alveolar flap [ɾ], which is voiced like [d] and sounds quite similar but is of course not the same sound.  Besides that, "with some speakers" is enough of an understatement to be incorrect.  And so on.

Comment: @snailboat: I am not using square brackets to indicate "close phonetic transcription" at all, simply to indicate a sound versus a letter.

Comment: @snailboat: When the lower jaw is retracted to produce /ar/ (as some speakers of AmE do) it is much easier to produce  a /d/ sound than a voiceless /t/ Perhaps some speakers of Indian English will produce a voiceless /t/  by pressing the tip of their tongues way back against the roof of the mouth (many BrE speakers do, those who thrust the lower jaw forward for /ar/), but no American does. Americans produce the voiceless /t/ against the ridge immediately behind the front teeth.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo
Thank you so much, I totally understand your answer :) Thanks for your time and effort. +1 from me :)